# Understanding chain rule for partial differentiation

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I cannot understand something regarding chain rule for partial differentiation.

Let $f(x,y)$. If I understand correctly, according to the chain rule we get:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}f(x,y)=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$

Now, for $u=x$, we end up with the term $\frac{\partial f\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x}$ in both sides of the equality; aren't we getting here some kind of loop?

$\frac{\partial f\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x} =\frac{\partial f\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f\left(x,y\right)}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=
 \frac{\partial f\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f\left(x,y\right)}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$

Comment: $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}=1$ and $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}=0$. So you have shown that $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} $ as expected.